# Why /#!/ is getting appended to my website's index.php page ? (I am using angular 1.x)

Tags: angularjs, web

I am using angular 1.x and the index page of my webapp is appended by /#!/ Please suggest possible outlook mistake.

Comment: Because you are not using HTML5 mode. https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a mistake and is exactly what is expected.  Essentially set html5mode to true and add a base link to to the head portion of your index page.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

This tutorial goes into more detail:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

More info on html5 history api

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Answer (score 0):

`$location` service has two configuration modes which control the format of the URL in the browser address bar: **Hashbang mode** (the default and that you are set in your app) and the HTML5 mode which is based on using the HTML5 History API.

On the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#browser-in-html5-fallback-mode-hashbang-mode-), you can read more about this and understand how this works.

Keep rocking!